# Update Values in a dataframe by merging

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have got two dataframes; the first is an **empty** one, with dates as rows and Products as columns. The second contains the **value** of the inventory, for a **specific item**.

The rows and the columns that are in the latter appear in the first one as well:

```
print(inventory_df)

dt_op        Prod_1  Prod_2 ... Prod_n
10/09/18       0        0         0
11/09/18       0        0         0
12/09/18       0        0         0

...

print(final_inspect)

    dt_op        Prod_1  
    10/09/18       10       
    11/09/18       2                
    12/09/18       5
```

I would like to update the values in *inventory_df*, obtaining the following dataframe:

```
print(updated_df)
    dt_op        Prod_1  Prod_2 ... Prod_n
    10/09/18      10        0         0
    11/09/18       2        0         0
    12/09/18       5        0         0

    ...
```

I tried with a redoundant method, concatenating and then removing duplicates, but when I use pd.concat it raises:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

How can I merge the first two frames to create the updated one?

N.B. The size of *updated_df* has to be the same as *inventory_df*, and nrows of *final_inspect* are less than nrows of *inventory_df*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)-

```
inventory_df.update(final_inspect)
```

**Output**

```
    dt_op   Prod_1  Prod_2
0   10/09/18    10  0
1   11/09/18    2   0
2   12/09/18    5   0
```

This by default implements a `join='left`, wherein you can take care of non-matching na values as you wish

Comment: It does not seem to produce a result; the function should be the right one but it does not update the dataframe. What could be the reasons?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli It updates the `df` inplace, i.e. the `inventory_df` is updated directly

Comment: I know, but at the moment, whenever I run "inventory_df.update(final_inspect)", inventory_df is not changed, even though there are not missing values, and the columns are the same.

Comment: Thats funny, not sure what might be going wrong, working fine for me :(

Comment: It does not work on my dataframe, nonetheless it does work with some other examples I've made for testing purposes.